# VMware VCSA 6.5 /storage/log full

Tags: storage, vmware-vsphere, log-files, virtual-appliances

I just came across this situation where my /storage/log partition on the VCSA was full and got the error "/storage/log is low on disk space or indoes":

[image]

All I found online was these two kbs by VMware:

1. Decrease the limit of the maximum log files and retention https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2143565
2. Increase partition size https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2126276

Problem is that I don't want to increase disk size and that the path /usr/lib/vmware-sso/vmware-sts/webapps/sts/WEB-INF/classes/ does not exist and I noticed that this is supposed to be fixed in 6.0 Update 3 and I have 6.5.

Any Ideas what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path does not exist most probably because this kb is for embedded PSC and I have external PSC - that explains why the directory vmware-sso was not under /usr/lib.

What I found was hprof files on /storage/log/vmware/perfcharts - found like 10 files weigh 700MB each.

After I searched online I found that these files are java crash dumps and are not good for anything but debugging so they could be safely deleted.

Since I found this on my own I am not responsible for any results of you guys doing it but I thought that this probably will be in use for someone.

---

Edit 14/11/17:

I found a VMware KB about the issue that states that it is OK to delete the files and also has a preventive solution:
https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2151394

Answer (score -1):

We are running VCSA 6.5 and implemented the fix in the article below : 
https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2151394

However , it did not seem to help . Ended up having to delete the files manually.